# Redirect the user to a new VF page and then to saved record detail page

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller

Onclick of custom Save button, the user will be redirected to the new VF page saying, The record has been saved successfully and press OK to proceed.
When user clicks on OK, then the user will be redirected to the newly created record detail page.

How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach**

Taking insertion of account as example in the approach, We will be using two redirects (PageReference in Apex Code)

1. Once the record is saved.
2. Once the user clicks on OK.

**Execution**

1. Create a command button that will call the apex function `insert()`

Button markup -

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!insert}" />
```

2. Add method to your class, this method will redirect to the proceed page with account id as parameter in url

> ```
> public pageReference insert(){
>     account acc = new account();
>     acc.name = 'testaccount';
>     insert acc;
>     PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/proceed?id='+acc.id);
>     pg.setRedirect(true);
>     return pg;
>     }
> ```

This code will take user to proceed page where the user will click on OK.

3.On the proceed page just add a command button which will redirect to the detail page of record.

```
<apex:commandButton value="OK" action="{!proceed}" />
```

Apex code

```
public pageReference proceed(){

PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
pg.setRedirect(true);
return pg;
}
```

Comment: @logan59 : i saw some typos , now corrected.